# How to make a wine shortcut for an .application file

Tags: wine

I have a windows app that uses the .application extension. I can open it in Thunar by double clicking it, or R-Click and open with rundll32. I want to create a .desktop shortcut to open this so I can use it in my menus and Thunar custom actions.

According to the wine wiki, rundll32 needs to be used as,

```
    wine rundll32 <dll_file>,<function> [function arguments]
```

but is the `<dllfile>` supposed to mean the .application file? Also, I'm not sure what function or arguments to use.

This is a snippet from an .exe shortcut that works:

```
    Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/akovia/.wine-dotnet40" wine C:\\\\Program\\ Files\\\\Windows\\ Program.exe
```

Thanks for any help that can be offered.

I've done some more poking around but still no joy. The .application file put a shortcut on my desktop `.appref-ms` that works if I double-click it, but creating a launcher to execute it fails.

Is there some way to see what command Thunar is using to launch either of these files and how to recreate it in a `.desktop` file?

Comment: Were you able to solve this 6 years ago? I also would like to launch an `.application` file from the command line.

Comment: Sorry but I stopped using wine not long after this. It's a shame that no one was ever able to comment on this. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

**`env WINEPREFIX="/opt/wineprefix/[tu_prefix]" wine start C:\\launcher\\Application.appref-ms`**

Replace [tu_prefix]

I hope it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you have a working shortcut to notepad in the default wine prefix:**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Notepad
Comment=Notepad
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/wingarmac/.wine" wine C:/windows/notepad.exe
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
GenericName=Wine application
Categories=Wine;
MimeType=application/x-ms-dos-executable;application/x-msi;application/x-ms-shortcut;
```

***Don't forget to change the user path in order to launch it in the right profile.***

Use the `wineconsole` command in a terminal instead of `wine` to make you able to follow debug information of it.

Example:

```
$ WINEPREFIX="/home/wingarmac/.wine" wineconsole C:/windows/notepad.exe
03ac:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (00000000000900C8, 1): stub
03ac:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (00000000000600E6, 00000000000900C8): stub
03b4:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (00000000000700B0, 0): stub
03b4:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (00000000000600CE, 00000000000700B0): stub
```

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by .application extension. Since Windows rarely uses extentions of more as 3 or 4  characters. What is the application you try to create a shortcut for exactly ?